# R shiny reactive plot and selectize default

Tags: r, shiny

UPDATE: Q2 has been answered. Thanks @Ben! Just looking for assistance with Q1 and selectize.

What I have: Using selectize the user can search a pension plan. **Q1: How can I avoid a default plan and simply have a "enter here..."?**

What I want: While the plan selection works fine, I'm trying to plot the age of plan members when that plan is selected. **Q2: How can I make my output (age) reactive to the input (plan name)?**

My **ui.r**:

```
fluidPage(    

  titlePanel("Atlantis Pension Dashboard"),
  sidebarLayout(      
    sidebarPanel(
      #Dynamic select type
      selectizeInput('Plan_Name', 'Search plan by keyword', choices = unique(Active$Plan_Name)),
      multiple = TRUE,

      #Static drop down
      selectInput('Plan_Name', "All plans", 
                  choices=unique(Active$Plan_Name)),
      hr(),
      helpText("Data from...")
    ),

    # Spot for hist
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("agePlot")  
    )))
```

and my **server.r**:

```
function(input, output) {

  Plan <- reactive(input$Plan_Name)

  # Dynamic plan select
  output$Plan_Name <- renderPrint({
    str(sapply(sprintf('Plan_Name'), function(id) {
      input[[id]]
    }, simplify = FALSE))
  })

  # Age histogram dependant on the chosed plan
  output$agePlot <- renderPlot({
    req(Plan())
    hist(Active[Plan()]$age)
  }

  )
}
```

What I've tried: damn near everything (being dumb doesn't help).

[image]

Comment: The problem comes from `Active[Plan()]$age`, what do you try to get with `Active[Plan()]`?

Comment: ERROR: undefined columns selected. I have to somehow specify I want a histogram of age for Plan() and I haven't seen an example of this technique which is why I'm so lost.

Comment: no I didn't mean "try to put `Active[Plan]`" but why do you put `Active[Plan]`? Can you put a subset of `Active` in your post?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm trying to do `hist(Active$age)` dependent on the Plan() which I've tried to define as the reactive determinant.

Comment: Please use `dput` on a subset of your data to generate the code to reproduce your data, and then post the result

Comment: Maybe you want something like: `hist(Active[Active$Plan_Name == input$Plan_Name, "age"])`

Comment: Ok, s/o @Ben for the simple fix. Jeez, thank you so much. I'm not entirely sure how it worked though....I didn't know `"age"` could reference `Active$age`

Comment: It's all in the same bracket...so the general format for subsetting a data frame is [rows, columns] ... so that statement extracts from `Active` rows where the `Plan_Name` in the data frame is == to the selected `input$Plan_Name` and selects just the column "age"